# Java: How to check which button was pressed?

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

Lets say i have something like this:

```
public class MyFrame implements ActionListener{
    private String title;

    public MyFrame(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }
    public void createFrame(){
        JFrame options = new JFrame("Options");

        options.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));

        options.add(createButton("Add"));
        options.add(createButton("Delete"));
        options.add(createButton("Search"));

        options.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        options.setVisible(true);
        options.pack();
    }

    private JButton createButton(String buttonName){
        JButton jb = new JButton(buttonName);
        jb.addActionListener(this);
        return jb;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //what to write here?
    }
}
```

My question is, how do i check which button was pressed? I was thinking about something like this but i don't really know how to implement my idea:

```
int result = //return a value after button pressed
if(result == something){
    //do something
}
```

I know this question has been asked many times but i didn't find any answers suitable for my case. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: how many buttons have you got? are you storing them into an array?

Comment: Ideally, each button should have its own listener, and the problem wouldn't even occur. Otherwise, take a look at `ActionEvent.getSource` method.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov should i create a different method for each button?

Comment: @sziko, If by that you mean a method on `MyFrame`, then no: you should create different classes that implement `ActionListener`. Each button that does something different should preferrably have its own instance of that `ActionListener` class.